# How to achive Multiple subscription through google play store for same app in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am building app in flutter with google in app subscription. Currenlty when user selects a subscription it shows payment screen with the primary email with which user has signed in in his android phone. The user is signed in my app with the same email and it works perfectly fine.
I am using in_app_purchase: ^3.1.1 in flutter for payment. It only returns the payment details when I check the user subscription which is the following

```
 {
  "orderId": "",
  "packageName": "",
  "productId": "",
  "purchaseTime": 1675329485078,
  "purchaseState": 0,
  "purchaseToken":"",
  "quantity": 1,
  "obfuscatedAccountId" : "",
  "autoRenewing": true,
  "acknowledged": false
};
```

If I log the user out from my app and log in again with different email id, I still receive same information and I can't buy the same subscription again.
Is there a way if I can buy two same subscriptions for different in app users which are using same android phone?

I tried to check if I can use different emails for different purchases. but what if user has only one primary email?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting the "Proration mode"

Official Link:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#change

Whenever a new user try to purchase a subscription you can bind the User ID to differentiate between a plan purchase on server.

Comment: But that is only for changing the "Base plans" which allows user to change from monthly to yearly billing. But if I have "Basic" and "Pro" plan with different possibilities in each, it does not apply

Comment: But according to Google Documentation its for all kind of paid plan can refer the above links example.